# Horizontal lines are showing up as low-resolution images

Tags: formatting, resolution

I'm trying to prepare a print-ready pdf file for a book. The publisher is complaining that horizontal lines (in particular, the lines separating headers and footers from the body, but I think it also happens for fraction bars) are showing up as low-resolution images (less than 72 dpi). I think that the following should be the relevant part of the preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage[paper height=9.21in, paperwidth=6.14in, top=.95in, bottom=.95in, 
inner=.75in, outer=.75in, head height=.6in, =.4in]{geometry}
```

I am compiling the document to a dvi file, and then converting it to a postscript file using

```
dvips -R -Poutline  -o filename.ps filename.dvi
```

The postscript file is then converted to a pdf file using Adobe Acrobat on the PDF/X-1a:2001 setting. I should also note that the document does contain a large number of actual images, all of which are included as eps files and have sufficiently high resolution.

> How can I make the horizontal lines come out as having resolution at least 72 dpi?  (At least 300 dpi would be ideal.)

Speculation: I can imagine that the -D option in dvips might be relevant, but I don't actually know, and I don't have an easy way to detect the results if I start playing around with it.

Comment: I really don't know what tags are appropriate here.  If someone does, please re-tag.

Comment: The *Command Line Option Details* of the [`dvips` documentation](http://www.radicaleye.com/dvipsman/dvips.html#SEC17) mentions the `-P <printer>` specifies a `config.<printer>` configuration file which option sets (amongst other things) the resolution. Perhaps something contained in `config.outline` is causing this drop in resolution?

Comment: Re detecting the results: [`pdfimages`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pdfimages1.html) may help - it will extract lines which are rendered as bitmap images for some reason but not vectors.

Comment: Further to my previous comment: `pdfimages` reveals that, with the workflow as above but using `ps2pdf` instead of Acrobat, both fraction bars and horizontal rules are rendered as a 1x1 black image which is stretched to the required size - hence the error with resolution. I'm not sure where in the process this is introduced - the PostScript file is not very friendly to my (relatively inexperienced) eyes. I did notice, however, that when the file is compiled directly with `pdflatex` the lines are rendered correctly as vectors - would this be an option for you?

Comment: One final note: I believe the distinction between vector and bitmap images in this case is academic - in both cases the instruction is to fill a particular area of the page with a single colour. I.e., despite the publishers' software complaining about low resolution, the lines should look as intended when output at any resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To repeat my comment above for the sake of writing a reasonably coherent answer, the reason your publishers' software is complaining is that both fraction bars and horizontal rules are being rendered as a 1x1 black image stretched to the required size.

This is caused by the `dvips` configuration you're using. If you keep the same workflow, but replace `-Poutline` with `-Ppdf` when running `dvips`, the horizontal lines are rendered correctly. (The `pdf` configuration is actually a superset of `outline`, so you're not losing anything from the configuration you had.)

(Edited to add: as a matter of fact, it turns out the only detail you need from `config.pdf` is `D 8000`: running

```
dvips -D8000 -Poutline whatever.dvi
```

is enough to make this work. `-D600` - i.e., a resolution of only 600 dpi - is not. I haven't experimented to see what the cutoff value is!)

Perhaps worth mentioning: alternative workflows would include using `pdflatex` in the first place, and using `dvipdfm` to go straight from DVI to PDF.

Comment: Thanks!  Also, thanks for the tip about pdfimages.  The publisher very strongly recommends that pdf files be compiled using Adobe Distiller (on a particular setting), which is why I am going through dvips.